# Running and communicating with php daemon script

Tags: php, apache, daemon

I am using a php library to access a private API. The library is not supposed to be run as a website but as a daemon to mimic an android application. The problem I am having is understanding how I'm supposed to write a php daemon that will watch for queries and how exactly I can communicate with it using a front end web server.

I've spent the better half of the day searching for some tutorials on exactly how to do it. I know there's are tools like GearmanManager and PHP-Daemon but I can't seem to find any tutorials on how to implement the code for my needs. I have written a php script that runs in the command line and dumps output but I just don't understand how I'm supposed to convert this to a daemon and communicate with it.

I'm basically want to send the daemon an id value that it will look up and dump out any output that it receives. Then have my front end webserver interpret it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "watch for queries"?

Comment: I'm not sure how to interact with the daemon. On a web interface, you use POST and GET to send queries to scripts. So I imagine you would do a similar thing with a daemon?

Comment: If you are asking about daemon program, why do you tag apache?

Comment: I'm not sure if a daemon program is needed at all. You may simply have a private webserver that serves your private API. That way don't have to deal with anything other than web interface.

Comment: If you really need it to be a daemon, you should read about [Socket](https://www.php.net/sockets) for direct socket connections.